# Python 3.6 ASCII inside hex bytes

Tags: python-3.x, binary, hex

I am receiving binary data, such as

```
data = b'\xaa\x44\x12\x1c\x2a'
```

When I try to parse each byte - what I am actually parsing is

```
b'\xaaD\x12\x1c*'
```

Is there a reason why bytes 44 and 2a are converted from HEX to ASCII?
Is there a way to prevent this conversion.

I have tried -

```
data = data.hex()
print(data.hex())
#print output aa44121c2a
```

Which does some what maintains the format but converts it to a string and cannot iterate through each byte but each character.
Any suggestions?